# "TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment" on a list object

Tags: python, database, list, sqlite, tuples

I imported a table from a database by using sqlite3, and then converted it to a list, even the type() function returned that the class was a list, but it still gave me that error message when I tried to change one of the cells

Here's my code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table1")
table = list(c.fetchall())
print(type(table))

table[0][0] = '10'
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH", line 9, in <module>
    table[0][0] = '10'
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: It's a list of tuples and tuples are immutable. You have to create a new list

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can you please tell me how to copy the values from the table to a new list? Because I've tried different methods but the outcomes were still the same

Comment: Can you post sample data stored in the variable `table` and also the expected output?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out, thank you so much for the answer, I replaced the code  table = list(c.fetchall()) by for i in c.fetchall(): table.append(list(i))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your list of tuples to a list of lists using the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function.

```
table = list(map(list, table))
```

Then you will be able to reassign `table[0][0]`, assuming such an element exists.